# WordPress category add image field

Tags: plugins, categories, custom-taxonomy

Checking for a possible solution to add a image upload field into category on posts in wordpress.
Like "Featured image" in posts. I checked different articles, some of them does display the upload form but not very precise on displaying the image in the frontend.
Any suggestion or help on this topic?
Thank you in advance
PS: better to skip the plugins :)

Answer (score 1):

[ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) allows you to attach fields to categories and taxonomies, and it has an image field. You'll need to update your template to call the field, but it will work like a charm.